# ¿Array de objetos, cambiar el valor de un atributo?

Tags: java, arraylist

Mi zoologico necesita agregar animales, para eso el usuario escribe:

- Numero de animales distintos que tendra el zoologico. (ej: 3)
- Nombre de animales distintos que tendra el zoologico (ej: Elefante, gorila, tigre)
- Cantidad de animales que se agregaran al zoologico (ej: 20 animales)

Se crean n cantidad de objetos (de la clase animal) que el usuario escribió. (ej: 10 elefantes, 5 gorilas, 5 tigres) y se almacenan en un arraylist de objetos.

```
public class Animal {
String nombre;
double tamaño; 
}
```

Esto lo tengo hecho, lo que quiero hacer es cambiar el valor del atributo **tamaño** de todos los animales que compartan el mismo nombre del array de objetos.

Ejemplo: todos los objetos con atributo **nombre** = "tigre", cambiar el valor del atributo llamado **tamaño** a 10. O sea todos los objetos de **nombre** "tigre" tendran **tamaño** 10. Todos los objetos de **nombre** "gorila" tendran **tamaño** 15, por ejemplo.

```
public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException {
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
    
    System.out.println("Escribe la cantidad de animales distintos que quieres agregar al zoologico: ");
    int animalesDistintos = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    
    String[] nombresAnimales = new String[animalesDistintos];
    
    System.out.println("Escribe el nombre de los animales que quieres agregar al zoologico: ");
    for(int x=0; x<animalesDistintos; x++)
    {
        System.out.print(x+">> ");
        String nombreAnimal = br.readLine();
        nombresAnimales[x] = nombreAnimal;
    }
    
    System.out.println("Escribe la cantidad de animales que quieres agregar al zoologico: ");
    int cantidadAnimales = Integer.parseInt(br.readLine());
    
    ArrayList<Animal> Animales = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int y=0; y<cantidadAnimales; y++)
    {
        Animal nuevoAnimal = new Animal(nombresAnimales[(int) (Math.random() * nombresAnimales.length)]);
        Animales.add(nuevoAnimal);
    }
    }
```

Comment: De qué manera estás inicializando tus objetos `Animal`?

Comment: edita tu  pregunta y agrega el código de como lo estás haciendo

Comment: El tamaño lo vas a cambiar de acuerdo a la cantidad de elementos que contengan ese nombre? es decir si en tu arreglo hay 5 tigres, que todos los objetos con nombre tigre tengan de `tamaño` 5  si hay 7 que sean 7, o van a ser valores estáticos, es decir que tigre siempre va a tener 10?

Comment: No importa el valor del atributo **tamaño** puede ser cualquier numero, solo necesito modificar el valor de todos los objetos que tengan igual **nombre**

Answer (score 0):

Para cambiar el valor de los atributos de un objeto necesitas `getters` y `setters` .

[Aquí te dejo un link dónde viene explicado](https://gl-epn-programacion-ii.blogspot.com/2010/03/setters-getters.html)

Básicamente son métodos que obtienen el valor del atributo del objeto y permiten cambiar tu ese valor.

En tu caso seria algo así:

```
Animales.get(0).setTamaño(Double Tamaño);
```

Espero que te sirva

Answer (score 0):

Puedes condicionarlo en el constructor con un switch

```
    public class Animal {
      String nombre;
      double tamaño;

      public Animal(String nombre) {
         this.nombre = nombre
         switch (nombre) {
            case 'tigre' :
              this.tamaño = 10;
              break;
           case 'otro_animal' :
             this.tamaño = 5;
             break;
         }
    }
```

Así al momento de crear el objeto animal `Animal animal =  new Animal('tigre');` el constrcutor le asignara la variable tamaño en automático

Como consejo extra, nunca le pongas a una variable caracteres como la ñ, ya que puede ocasionar problemas al momento de compilar, puedes cambiar el nombre a `tamanio` por ejemplo

Comment: Este codigo logro solucionar la duda que tenía, Gracias a ti Sr1871.

Comment: si encontraste la solución te sugiero marcar la respuesta, saludos.

Answer (score 0):

Un approach trabajando con Java 8 es mediante la utilización de los Streams. Esto nos permite no meter lógica en nuestro constructor de clase que poco tiene que ver con la creación del mismo.

En este caso lo usaremos con `filter()` y `map()` para poder transformar cada valor de arreglo que sea "tigre" (en este caso) para que su tamaño sea de 10.

```
    List<Animal> animales = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    Animal a1 = new Animal("tigre", 8);
    Animal a2 = new Animal("paloma", 4);
    animales.add(a1);
    animales.add(a2);
    
    List<Animal> transformedAnimals = animales.stream()
        .filter(p -> p.nombre == "tigre")
        .map(p -> new Animal(p.nombre, 10) )
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    System.out.println(transformedAnimals.size()); //Output: 1
```

Después combinamos nuestro nuevo array con el anterior para posteriormente juntarlos quitando los duplicados que no cumplan con nuestro filtro

```
    List<Animal> combineList = new ArrayList<Animal>();
    combineList.addAll(animales);
    combineList.addAll(transformedAnimals);
    
    System.out.println(combineList.size()); // Output: 3
    
    
    List<Animal> result = combineList.stream()
        .filter((p) -> {
            if(p.nombre == "tigre" && p.tamaño < 10) { // Quitamos los que no cumplan con el filtro (se puede metodizar para mayor flexibilidad)
             return false;   
            } else {
                return true;
            }
        })
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
    
    
    System.out.println(result.size()); // Output: 2
```